# How to decrypt mp4 PKCS8 encoded file using private key in node js and crypto

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I'm trying to decrypt a MP4 file that is encrypted using public key in pkcs8 format in Node JS and private key.

I tried this code:

```
var decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt({ key: privateKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING }, buffer);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error: error:0406506C:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:data greater than mod len

I'm currently using this Java code that is working. I would like to swich to Node JS

```
final byte[] cekWrapped = Base64.getDecoder().decode(conn.getHeaderField("x-amz-meta-x-amz-key").getBytes());
        final byte[] iv = Base64.getDecoder().decode(conn.getHeaderField("x-amz-meta-x-amz-iv").getBytes());
        // Now we need to decrypt the envelope
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(privateKey.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        final byte[] decryptedSymmetricKeyBytes = cipher.doFinal(cekWrapped);
        final SecretKeySpec cek = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedSymmetricKeyBytes, "AES");

        // Once we have the symmetric master key, we can decrypt the contents
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        try {
            cipher.init(DECRYPT_MODE, cek, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        } catch (final InvalidKeyException e) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Invalid key exception. Please make sure that Java Cryptography Extensions with unlimited " +
                            "jurisdiction are installed");
        }
        try (final InputStream in = conn.getInputStream()) {
            try (final CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher)) {
                try (final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination.toFile())) {
                    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = cis.read(b)) >= 0) {
                        fos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: PKCS#8 is the form of the private key, not of the encrypted file. You should indicate the protocol scheme, otherwise answering this is impossible.

Comment: I've added the Java code that I'm currently using

Answer (score 0):

RSA uses the difficulty of factoring large semi-primes as it's trap-door function.

As part of the RSA crypto-system two primes are generated during public/private key creation.

We call the two primes `p` and `q`. They multiply to form `n`, which is the modulus (a semi-prime).

Although RSA can be used to to encrypt data directly (via `c=m^e mod{n}`), you cannot encrypt data larger than the modulus directly.

Therefore if you are using `2048-bit` primes to generate `n`, you can only encrypt `4096-bit`s of information directly with the keys (in practice even a little less).

Instead, for large data you need to generate a random symmetric key and send it to your counterpart encrypting it with their RSA public key, and then use the agreed key with a symmetric cipher like `AES-GCM` or `xSalsa20`.

Really though, you should move to using ECDH over elliptic curves.

tldr: If you encrypt some data with RSA, where data.length > modulus.length, you're gonna get nonsense when you decrypt it.